# Canvas - desenhar imagem repetida

Tags: javascript, canvas

Como posso desenhar uma imagem a repetindo até preencher uma área?
Algo como o efeito da propriedade CSS `background-repeat`.
Onde a imagem é repetida até preencher toda a área da tag.

Comment: Queres fazer isso com Canvas? podes explicar melhor a pergunta? tens alguma imagem em canvas?

Comment: @Sergio sim, com canvas. Quero usar a função context.drawImage() para desenhar uma imagem, mas ela precisa repetir do mesmo jeito que uma backgroud de uma tag com a propriedade CSS `background-repeat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A API do canvas tem uma funcionalidade para padrões.

Um exemplo:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("my_canvas"),
context = canvas.getContext("2d"),

var img = new Image();

img.src = 'http://bit.ly/2fDRYfC';

img.onload = function(){
    var pattern = context.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
    context.fillStyle = pattern;
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Comment: Eu lhe agradeço, desculpe não marcar como respondido antes é que simplesmente havia me esquecido.